# Combining 2-dimensional array (matrix) elements

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, loops, matrix

I have a 2-dimensional array like **[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]**.

So I need to combine every element with all the others form another sublists ang get an array like **[[1,4,7], [1,4,8], [1,4,9], [2,4,7], [2,4,8], [2,4,9], [3,4,7], [3,4,8], [3,4,9], [1,5,7], [...], [...], ... etc]** in **Python3**.

**!** The number of sublists may be different.

I have used different approaches with loops but nothing works correctly. How can I do that **without using itertools**? Thanks in advance!

I tried iterating arrays but I could not fully embody the idea.

```
arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
total = []
for i in arr[0]:
    for index, j in enumerate(arr[1:]):
        res = [i]
        for indx, n in enumerate(j):
            res.append(n)
            for m in arr[index+1]:
                res.append(m)
                break
        print(res)
```

And I got only this

[1, 4, 4, 5, 4, 6, 4]
[1, 7, 7, 8, 7, 9, 7]
[2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 6, 4]
[2, 7, 7, 8, 7, 9, 7]
[3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 6, 4]
[3, 7, 7, 8, 7, 9, 7]  .. which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the cartesian product from itertools

```
from  itertools import product
arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
prod = product(*arr)
print(list(prod))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that I need a solution without using itertools :(

Comment: The Python doc provides a "roughly equivalent" implementation of itertools.product: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.product